# Trying to run a transfer learning with music data

Tags: python-3.x, github, google-colaboratory

I am trying to execute github code in the following repository:

https://github.com/shubham3121/music-generation-using-rnn
The error is in the following function:

```
def generate():
    """ Generate a piano midi file """
    #load the notes used to train the model
    with open('data/notes', 'rb') as filepath:
        notes = pickle.load(filepath)

    # Get all pitch names
    pitchnames = sorted(set(item for item in notes))
    # Get all pitch names
    n_vocab = len(set(notes))

    print('Initiating music generation process.......')

    network_input = get_inputSequences(notes, pitchnames, n_vocab)
    model = create_network(normalized_input, n_vocab)
    print('Loading Model weights.....')
    model.load_weights('weights.best.music3.hdf5')
    print('Model Loaded')
    prediction_output = generate_notes(model, network_input, pitchnames, n_vocab)
    create_midi(prediction_output)
```

The problem is as follows:

```
Initiating music generation process.......

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-24-b97e0091fa1b> in <module>()
----> 1 generate()

<ipython-input-20-27d37a8858b8> in generate()
     13 
     14     network_input = get_inputSequences(notes, pitchnames, n_vocab)
---> 15     model = create_network(normalized_input, n_vocab)
     16     print('Loading Model weights.....')
     17     model.load_weights('weights.best.music3.hdf5')

NameError: name 'normalized_input' is not defined
```

Since the code is not mine, I don't know what this variable is so I can fix it ...
I emailed the code owner, but he didn't respond.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume the actual code is [here](https://github.com/shubham3121/music-generation-using-rnn/blob/master/Jazz%20Music%20Sampling%20.ipynb)

Not 100% sure, but most likely error in the code. Supposed to be **network_input**. So you change

```
network_input = get_inputSequences(notes, pitchnames, n_vocab)
model = create_network(normalized_input, n_vocab)
```

to

```
network_input = get_inputSequences(notes, pitchnames, n_vocab)
model = create_network(network_input, n_vocab)
```

This generates the following error:

```
Initiating music generation process.......

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-27-b97e0091fa1b> in <module>()
----> 1 generate()

1 frames

<ipython-input-14-866d26da5fd7> in create_network(network_in, n_vocab)
      4     """Create the model architecture"""
      5     model = Sequential()
----> 6     model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=network_in.shape[1:], return_sequences=True))
      7     model.add(Dropout(0.2))
      8     model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Okay, if you look at the code from

```
In [7]: def prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab):
```

You can see a conversion to numpy array:

```
network_input = np.reshape(network_input, (n_patterns, sequence_length, 1))
```

You should do something similar to get_inputSequences so you return numpy array, not regular python list. But the code looks old, so even if you fix the error, you may have unexpected result, so better to figure it out under github. Alternatively you need to fix and make sure you get good results, if not you need to get involved into the code.

Comment: I've had already tested with this option, it does not work either :(

Comment: I edited with your error message... hm...this is weird. I will edit again, I have an idea, but it's better to contact vendor

Comment: I edited, you can easily fix the error, but you have to make sure the code produce right results

Comment: Thats the problem I've already contected the guy but I didnt get any answer

Comment: Github is a public area. You can open **Issues** tab and describe what you found. The code was updated two years ago, so there is some chance.

Comment: Already!!! See this: https://github.com/shubham3121/music-generation-using-rnn/issues/1

Comment: LLIaMaHa suggests the same thing, but to do it right inside the "generate()" function

Comment: I did it and get another error:
Put it there https://github.com/shubham3121/music-generation-using-rnn/issues/1#issuecomment-554654847